# Microphone no longer works on Firefox, how to revert settings of pavucontrol?

Tags: pavucontrol

I messed up on `pavucontrol` and now my microphone doesn't work on Firefox (although it works with another non-root user account) so how can I revert settings back to their original state for what concerns `pavucontrol`?

Thank you very much in advance for any help on this.

Comment: If you're sure the reason for the problem is only because you've messed the settings, try  
`rm ~/.config/pulse`
or rename it to another file.
It will force pavucontrol to generate a new user-file.

Comment: @AkhilBaranwal thank you so much, let me see if it will work :)

Comment: @AkhilBaranwal yup it works!!!!!!!!!!!!11!1 Please write an answer so that I can accept it and you get the sweet reputation you so deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the reason for the problem is only because you've messed the settings, try `rm ~/.config/pulse` or rename it to another file. It will force pavucontrol to generate a new user-file.